# WebView2 JS injection returns empty json string

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, webview2

With WebView2 for targeting Windows, I am trying to setup my own context menu.
Either by selected text or by underlying element pointed by mouse click.

However, I can't get DOM element by mouse operation or even by byId.
I think my JavaScript injection or WebView property setting is something wrong, but not too sure.
Can anyone suggest me the resolution?

The version info.

- OS : Windows 10 Pro 21H2 19044.1682
- Visual Studio : Community 2022 17.1.6
- WebView2 : 1.0.1185.39
- Project Property: Target framework=.NET 6.0; Target OS version=10.0.19041.0

Here's the testing code

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HTML(@"C:\temp\test.html");
        }
        public void HTML(string url)
        {
            webView21.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView2Control_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
            webView21.Source = new Uri(url);
        }
        private void WebView2Control_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsSuccess)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"WebView2 creation failed, with exception : {e.InitializationException}");
                return;
            }
            // subscribe to events we are interested in
            webView21.CoreWebView2.ContextMenuRequested += CoreWebView2_ContextMenuRequested;       // user clicked right mouse to show context menu
        }
        private async void CoreWebView2_ContextMenuRequested(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2ContextMenuRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            IList<CoreWebView2ContextMenuItem> menuItemList = e.MenuItems;
            menuItemList.Clear();  // clear default menu items, like prev, next, property

            //GETTING SELECTED TEXT
            string text = e.ContextMenuTarget.HasSelection ? e.ContextMenuTarget.SelectionText : ""; // it works

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))  // no text selection, then examine DOM
            {
            //GET AN UNDERLYING ELEMENT FROM MOUSE POINT
                var result = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.elementFromPoint({e.Location.X},{e.Location.Y})");   //it doesn't work, just returns an empty JSON text (not null)
                //var result = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("function foo(){return 'foo() gets called';}; foo();");  //for testing purpose, it works
                //var result = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("function foo(){return document.getElementById('table-content'};foo();)");   //it returns an empty result
            }
            // TO DO
            // setup menuItem tree based on the result we got
            //......
            //......
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.elementFromPoint` returns a DOM element. That can't be used in `WebView2`. You must write javascript code, that does what you want and return the result to C#.

Comment: thank you.
I thought ExecuteScriptAsync may return snippet of HTML text, but i was wrong.
Will look into DOM handling codes on JS.

Comment: If you want the text of the element, you can do: `$"document.elementFromPoint({e.Location.X},{e.Location.Y}).textContent"`. You just can't return a `HTMLElement`, but text works fine.

Comment: yep, i understand now, host needs to receive a string but not DOM element.

Comment: This is described more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/javascript#scenario-executescript-json-encoded-results. The JSON encoding only serializes owned properties and DOM objects generally don't have any own properties. So you can return script objects via ExecuteScriptAsync but you won't get what you expect from DOM objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think i managed it, thanks for insights given.
My original intent was to capture innerText and href and to feed them to C# code(host).
one note. getter/setter has to be ready.
Here's complete test code.

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HTML(@"C:\temp\test.html");
        }
        public void HTML(string url)
        {
            webView21.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView2Control_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
            this.webView21.Source = new Uri(url);
        }
        private void WebView2Control_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsSuccess)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"WebView2 creation failed, with exception : {e.InitializationException}");
                return;
            }
            // subscribe to events we are interested in
            webView21.CoreWebView2.ContextMenuRequested += CoreWebView2_ContextMenuRequested;       // user clicked right mouse to show context menu
        }
        public class HTMLelements
        {
            public string href { get; set; } = "";
            public string innerText { get; set; } = "";
        }
        private async void CoreWebView2_ContextMenuRequested(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2ContextMenuRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            IList<CoreWebView2ContextMenuItem> menuItemList = e.MenuItems;
            menuItemList.Clear();  // clear default menu items, like prev, next, property

            HTMLelements htmlElements = new(); //Didn't know this new syntax

            //GETTING SELECTED TEXT
            htmlElements.innerText = e.ContextMenuTarget.HasSelection ? e.ContextMenuTarget.SelectionText : "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlElements.innerText))  // no text selection, then examine DOM
            {
                //GETTING AN UNDERLYING ELEMENT FROM MOUSE POINT
                //it should return JSON string { "href" : "something or empty", "innerText: "something" }
                string jScript = $@"
                    function GetElement() {{
                        var elem = document.elementFromPoint({ e.Location.X},{ e.Location.Y});
                        var obj = new Object();
                        obj.href = elem.href === undefined? '' : elem.href;
                        obj.innerText = elem.innerText;
                        return obj;
                    }};
                    GetElement();";

                var result = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(jScript);
                htmlElements = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HTMLelements>(result); // feed them to our class object
            }
            // TO DO
            //setup menuItem tree based on the result we got
            //setting up CoreWebView2ContextMenuItem is new to me, hence I use C# standard toolStripMenuItem instead.
            //sometime later, I will amend as such
            toolStripMenuItemPlaceHolder.Text = htmlElements.innerText;
            toolStripMenuItemPlaceHolder.Enabled = true;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlElements.href))
            {
                toolStripMenuItemPlaceHolder.Tag = htmlElements.href;
                toolStripMenuItemShowInBrowser.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                toolStripMenuItemPlaceHolder.Tag = null;
                toolStripMenuItemShowInBrowser.Enabled = false;
            }
            contextMenuStripInBrowser.Show(webView21, e.Location);

            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
}
```